# Fixed effects IV: exogenous covariates changing

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables

Currently, I have 2 endogenous binary variables of interest (call these the VOIs) and 3 instrumental variables(all of which are also dummy variables), allowing me to use the overidentification test to test whether the instruments are endogenous. I also have several dummies for time (i.e. a dummy for the years 1960-1969, 1970-1979 etc.) which I assume to be exogenous variables.

1) To test for the relevance of the instruments, I first estimated a fixed effects model with clustered residuals of the VOIs on the 3 instrumental variables only. This gave me very high F-values (15.57 and 9.70) for the regression, showing that the instrumental variables are relevant.

However, when I ran the same first-stage fixed effects model of the VOIs on the 3 instrumental variables AND the decade-dummies, the F values drops drastically  to ~7.80 and 5.70 respectively. Does this result affect the relevance of my 3 instrumental variables? How should I interpret this difference?

2) I then estimated the main model of interest using xtivreg in stata with and without the decade-dummies included. However, the estimated coefficients of the VOIs change drastically when the decade-dummies are added: dropping from 11.5 to 1.6. However, in both cases, the overidentification test shows that the instruments and time dummies are all uncorrelated with the error term (Sargan-test p-value of 0.895 without decade-dummies and 0.343 with decade dummies). Do these differing results still indicate that the 3 instruments are uncorrelated with the residuals of the main regression? If so, why would adding time-variables drastically change the VOIs coefficients if the 3 IVs are supposed to make the VOIs exogenous?

Thanks for your help!